# Uploadify refuses to upload WMV, FLV and MP4 files

Tags: jquery, upload, uploadify, file-type

The [uploadify plugin for JQuery](http://www.uploadify.com/) seems very good and works for most file types. However, it allows me to upload all file types apart from the ones I need.

Uploads of any other type work.

- I have already tried changing the fileExt parameter and also tried removing it altogether.
- I have testing in Google Chrome, IE7 and Firefox and none work for these file types.
- I have a ton of local projects already and uploading is not an issue on any other project, I even use the same example files (This is the first time I have used Uploadify)

Is there a known reason for this behaviour?

**EDIT: Have found the issue. I had forgotten to add my usual .htaccess file to the example project which amends PHP to allow large file sizes. I will hang my head in shame for the rest of the day.**

Comment: Sure it is uloadify, and not the host that refuses the file?

Comment: I am just running the example scipt locally at the moment, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Shouldn't be or really isn't? Did you try simply upload with a html form and a file-input field? Does that work? What do you use server-side? PHP check if file-uploading is even enabled and if you have set a size restriction on uploaded files

Comment: Thanks jitter, have sorted the issue now!

Comment: you can add an answer to the question and accept it when it becomes possible in 24 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am ashamed to admit that I did not follow the list of [dumb things to check](http://everythingsysadmin.com/dumb-things-to-check.html).

The issue was actually because my php upload setting was set too low.

I have now added this to my php ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
post_max_size = 1024M
```

I use a .htaccess file on all my projects but obviously forgot to add it when setting up this uploadify example.