# Upload flv file by SwfUpload #2038 error

Tags: jquery, uploadify, swfupload

I Use jquery **uploadify** plugin to upload jpg, png, gif and flv file to server.

Pictures files (jpg, png, gif) uploaded successfully, but when I try to upload a **flv** file, I get **error 2038**. Very strange, that error occurred internal swfupload module.

Firebug shows that the error occurs on the client, as the file is not transfered to the server.

Please help me solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IIS 7+ then try to setup max allowed content length property in your Web.config file.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="50000" maxAllowedContentLength="1000000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Also you can see explanation there [Uploadify refuses to upload WMV, FLV and MP4 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492155/uploadify-refuses-to-upload-wmv-flv-and-mp4-files-solved)